# Ubuntu Server problem with eth0 and wlan0 on RPi

Tags: networking, server, ssh, raspberrypi

I flashed the img ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz onto an sd card and boot it up on an Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. Since I'm doing this headlessly, I have to connect it through ssh. Anyway, I want to run the server through wlan, so I did a bit of research online and edited /etc/network/interfaces. This is what it looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.135
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
     wpa-essid "somessid"
     wpa-psk "somekey"
```

As soon as I removed the LAN cable, i get Destination Host Unreachable when I try to ping both IP. Sometimes, it doesn't even work if I plug the LAN cable back on. I'm new to both Ubuntu Server and Raspberry Pi and I know this has been asked a lot but I haven't been able to get it done (believe me, this is the 9th time that I flash my sd card.) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe it is `wpa-ssid` and you also need dns-namervers if you expect to reach the internet.

Comment: I mean I still can connect with the wlan0 IP with the LAN cable on, but not without it. I tried dns nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1 but it still doesn't work

Comment: Once you correct your interfaces file and reboot with the ethernet detached, does it connect?

Comment: I rebooted with corrected file and ethernet detached and connect the server with wlan0 ip, all I get is connection timed out

Comment: [image](https://scontent.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/20464385_1941732869431456_1422106322_n.png?oh=c76a8d9b3a5f96f7301f5236433e0b10&oe=597E30D3)

Comment: Please post your corrected interfaces file here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also add to the paste: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep wlan`

Comment: [interfaces](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25194036/) [wlanlog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25194041/)

Comment: May I also see: `ifconfig` also in a paste?

Comment: [ifconfig](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25194238/)